# Overwrite Java based Spring Context Configuration for Tests

Tags: spring, configuration, config

Is there a possibility to replace a single bean or value from a Spring configuration for one or more integration tests?

In my case, I have the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"})
public class MyIntegrationTestConfig {
    // everything done by component scan
}
```

Which is used for my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyIntegrationTestConfig.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    // do the tests
}
```

Now I want to have a second set of integration tests where I replace one bean by a different one.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyIntegrationTestConfig.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MySpecialIntegrationTest {
    // influence the context configuration such that a bean different from the primary is loaded

    // do the tests using the 'overwritten' bean
}
```

What is the most simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Spring test framework is able to understand extension over configuration. It means that you only need to extend `MySpecialIntegrationTest` from `MyIntegrationTest`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MySpecialIntegrationTestConfig.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
public class MySpecialIntegrationTest extends MyIntegrationTest {

  @Configuration
  public static class MySpecialIntegrationTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyBean theBean() {}
  }

}
```

and create the necessary Java Config class and provide it to `@ContextConfiguration`. Spring will load the base one and extend it with the one that you specialize in your extended test case.

Refer to the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) for further discussion.